# Is there a c# library that supports the parsing and execution of T-sql scripts on SQL CE

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, scripting, sql-server-ce

I know SQL CE does not support Transact SQL. However, I would think there would be a library out there that can parse a Transact SQL file (at least a subset for TSQL) and execute it for me. For now, I'm really only looking for the if else functionality (as well as all that SQL CE already supports), but I'm sure I'll need more soon. Is there anything out there that can do this?

Basically, I would write the TSQL. I would pass it to this library. Anything SQL CE can execute, the library would pass it down. Anything it could not execute, such as an if else, would have to be executed by the C# code, i.e. in the library.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect this is overly ambitious. Personally, I would find it hard to trust such a tool...

Comment: You can use my scripting library: http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

I believe, technically, it is a subset of T-SQL, so it supports a great deal of the syntax. TOP, HAVING, DISTINCT, and a few other choice words are not allowed. Unfortunately, I know of no library that will translate for you. The problem is many, if not most/all, of the missing items have no way to duplicate in SQL only solution.

Comment: Like i said, if whatever it was could add the "IF ELSE" functionality which is missing it would be great. It could also add other missing commands such as GETUTCDATE maybe, etc. I'm not asking for something THAT complicated i don't think